# pip and private repositories

Tags: pip, setuptools, drone.io

I'm deploying a python application and I'm trying to create a pipeline with [Drone.io](https://www.drone.io/)
In my main application, I have multiple dependencies that are located in private Github repositories `requirements.txt`:

```
git+ssh://git@hostname_A/org/repo_A.git
git+ssh://git@hostname_B/org/repo_B.git
```

For each repository, I have a Github `Deploy Key`.
So my `.drone.yml` contains the multiple deploy keys store in drone secrets.
Inside my container, I'm copying a `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host hostname_A
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/repo_A_rsa

Host hostname_B
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/repo_B_rsa
```

The issue is that the repository/package `repo_B` also has a dependency with the private repository `repo_A`.
And I don't know how to link this private repository, I have tried to add `install_requires` and `dependency_links` inside the `setup.py` of `repo_B`:

```
setuptools.setup(
    name="repo_B",
    install_requires=[
        "repo_A_alias @ git+ssh://git@hostname_A/org/repo_A.git"
    ],
)
```

But I still get the error:

```
collecting repo_B @ git+ssh://git@github.com/org/repo_B.git
  Cloning ssh://****@github.com/org/repo_B.git to /tmp/pip-install-naymvvlo/repo_B_67066986e78c4124b8cc99242aeaa673
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'ssh://****@github.com/org/repo_B.git' /tmp/pip-install-naymvvlo/repo_B_67066986e78c4124b8cc99242aeaa673 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Or is there a way to access the log file?